# How to use train_date.take(1) with Tensorflow

Tags: python, database, tensorflow, keras, batchsize

I'm working on a test with tensorflow. I have my dataset into two folders. I configured the `batch_size`, `height` and `width` for the `train_data` but then i can't see them with `matplotlib` or use it in the model.

```py
#Import dataset
import pathlib
import os

data_dir = pathlib.Path(r'C:\Users\vion1\Ele\Engie\Exercices\DL\Pikachu\dataset')
image_count = len(list(data_dir.glob('*/*')))
print(image_count)
#374

batch_size = 32
img_height = 256
img_width = 256

train_data = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=42,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size,
  )

class_names = train_data.class_names
print(train_data)
#Found 374 files belonging to 2 classes.
#Using 300 files for training.
#<BatchDataset shapes: ((None, 256, 256, 3), (None,)), types: (tf.float32, tf.int32)>

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
for images, labels in train_data.take(1):
  for i in range(3):
    ax = plt.subplot(1, 3, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
    plt.axis("off")
```

The error is :

```
InvalidArgumentError: Unknown image file format. One of JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP required.
     [[{{node decode_image/DecodeImage}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNext]
```

I think that `train_date.take(1)` doesn't take the file but i can't understand why and how to fix it, any idea?

Comment: The code looks fine. Probably at least one of your images is corrupted. You can check whether any image is corrupted or not with [this](https://gist.github.com/Kaveh8/9a8e1097b76c8ee92a4644f4413fa57f) snippet.

Comment: Thx a lot for the comment (and the edit), i had no idea my files can be corrupted here. Now i have another problem but not the same ! I could not find the solution without your help, thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code which you have mentioned looks proper, the main reason for failure could be as per the error is that one or more file in your `tf.data.Dataset` does not belong to any of the mentioned file extension.
To check the corrupted file you can refer the below code.
Here I'm taking the example dataset mentioned in the [document](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import PIL
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import keras

import pathlib
dataset_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('flower_photos', origin=dataset_url, untar=True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)

roses = list(data_dir.glob('roses/*'))
```

Now, leet's check the unique filenames in the roses directory.

```
file_names = [str(i) for i in roses]
unique_files = set(i.split('.')[-1] for i in file_names)
print(unique_files)

Output:
{'jpg'}
```

In the output directory if you get any filetypes other than allowed filetypes, you need to recheck your data.
Else you can follow [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification) document for same procedure.